# Send Data From app.vue to Page in Nuxt.js 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm making a registration page, and if the user is logged in I need to send the user object from the `app.vue` file to every page in the `pages/` directory. Here's the `app.vue`:

```
<script setup>

import { ref } from 'vue';

const userId = useCookie('user');

const userObj = await $fetch('/api/user/getLoggedInUser', {
    method: 'post',
    body: {
        id: userId.value
    }
});

const user = ref(userObj);

</script>


<template>
    <div>
        <Header />
        <NuxtLayout>
            <NuxtPage :user="user.value" />
        </NuxtLayout>
    </div>
</template>
```

How would I get the user in `/pages/index.vue`, or any of the files in that directory?

Answer (score 0):

When I need to handle user authentication I usually like to use `@vueuse` `useLocalStorage`, which is basically a wrapper for reactive local storage, so the user stays logged in between sessions. You need to:

- Authenticate the user
- Save the user object/response in the localStorage (your `userObj`)
- Access it wherever you need

Example:

```js
// useUser composable
export const useUser = () => {
  const user = useLocalStorage("user", null); // by default is not logged in, so null or some other value you can check

  const login = async() => {
    const userObj = await ...;
    user.value = userObj; // here you set the user in the storage
  }

  return {
    user,
    login
  }
}
```

Then where you need to auth the user:

```js
const { login } = useUser();

await login();
```

And where you need to access the user object:

```js
const { user } = useUser();

const someData = user.someValue;
```

The user object will persist until you manually empty the localStorage, or until you create a logout function which clears the storage key and logs out the user.

Comment: In the login function, what should I put in the userObj? (`const userObj = await ...;`). To login, I have a server route that logs the user in, and takes in an email and a password. How would I send the through this login function?

Comment: It's just the function you use in order to login the user, you need to edit it a little bit to reflect the params you need, like in your post you use `$fetch` and send a request for that. `userObj` is the result of the login operation, and then you save that to the storage.

Comment: So in the `useUser` composable I ended up doing this: `export const useUser = async () => {
    const userId = useCookie('user');

    if (userId.value) {
        const user = await $fetch('/api/user/getLoggedInUser', {
            method: 'post',
            body: {
                id: userId.value
            }
        });

        return useState('user', () => user);
    } else {
        return useState('user', () => '');
    }
}`, but when I get the composable `const user = await useUser();` I get this error: **[nuxt] [request error] nuxt instance unavailable**

Comment: Maybe there's some logic to rework, I don't think the cookie is needed but that is surely the right direction. Composables lets you reuse a lot of code

Comment: No, there isn't any problem with the cookie, its the async operations. I can't get the async/await to work.